# Difference between insert new data using instance of new object or using .create

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

What's the diference between these two ways?

Example:

```
var user = new User({
    user.name = "Blabla",
    user.password = "blabla"
});


User.create({name:req.body.blabla, password:req.body.blablabla},callback func)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is simply instantiating a new user instance before saving to the database.

```
var user = new User({
  user.name = "Blabla",
  user.password = "blabla"
});
```

You'll need to save it to the database like this

```
user.save(callback)
```

However, the second implementation has `save` as part of its internal implementation. So, it basically instantiate the `User` model and save the new instance